# Div/span in table-td is removed. Pasting in TinyMCE

Tags: html, xhtml, tinymce

I have a table in a TinyMCE template and in TD have used DIV/SPAN/P but when pasted in editor from template DIV/SPAN/P is removed.

Anyone know what you use which is not removed. Actually I want to display google map in certain element.?

```
<table class="ver-mainbox-table">

           <tr class="ver-mainbox-tr">
                <td class="ver-mainbox-txt">
                    Your Text Here
                </td>               
                <td class="ver-mainbox-img">
                   <p id="map_dallas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="spacer-m" colspan="2"></td></tr>
           <tr class="ver-mainbox-tr">
                <td class="ver-mainbox-txt">
                    Your Text Here
                </td>               
                <td class="ver-mainbox-img">
                   <p id="map_frisco" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it's because the elements are empty?

Comment: @ray , hmm let me check. Yes they are empty.

Comment: So, try to fill them with some content, to see what's happening in TinyMCE. Check if the map is still visible even when the element has some content. Play around with the code. Just a bit of trail and error.

Comment: @ray , it was empty problem. Thanks

Comment: @Ray: you may post your answer as an answer. pirzada may accept it then

Answer (score -1):

As said in the comments:
TinyMCE removes all empty elements, so add some content to the elements and TinyMCE wouldn't remove the elements any more.